# I want to know a form of a "Repeat until" block in scratch in python?

Tags: python, mit-scratch

I need some help, you know those "repeat until" blocks in scratch? Well I need to know how to do that in python. What I want to do is this, with a repeat block.

```
retry = True
if password = "password1234":
    retry = False
else:
    pass
```

Comment: so you want to be in a loop untill password == "password1234" , is my understanding correct?

Comment: A do-while loop will solve that...

Comment: @kenntnisse "do-while"? In Python? Did I miss something?

Comment: I want to put this whole code in a "repeat until" block.

Comment: @VMSMani Yes, but I have some code "password = input("What's your password?")" and then I want the variable password to save(Permently, even if you reboot the program.), so then when you put it in... ITS BASICLLY A SIGN IN PAGE, OK?

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet checks if the password is `"password1234"`. If it is correct, it changes the flag to `False` and hence the loop terminates. Otherwise, it will do further processing (e.g., ask the user for a new input).

```
retry = True
password = ""
while (retry):
  # Check if the password equals to a specific password.
  if (password == "password1234"):
    retry = False
  else:
    # Do further processing here.
    # Example: ask the user for the password
    password = input("Enter a password: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Program will be asking you for password until you type **password1234**

```
password = input("Enter you password")
while password!="password1234":
    password = input("Enter you password")
```

Comment: wow this is the most shortest one ive seen, +15 social credit points

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions are also correct. But if you want to keep your style, try this:

```
def get_password():
    retry = True
    password = input("Password: ")
    if retry:
        if password == "password1234":
            retry = False
        else:
            return get_password()

get_password()
```